# What does it mean to say "something over set"?

Tags: terminology

For example, when it comes to strings and languages, we say that an alphabet is any finite set and a **string over alphabet** is a finite sequence of symbols from the alphabet.

What does, "string over alphabet," mean?

Does it mean that just that, "a finite sequence of symbols from the alphabet"?

Maybe I am confused by subsets, which we know to be unordered. Is this concept similar, but a sequence of values from a set, therefore ordered?

Comment: Yes, though it does not need to be finite.  If $A$ is the underlying alphabet then a string over $A$ is just a sequence $s_1s_2\cdots$ where $s_n\in A$ for all $n$.  It is usually written in concatenated form, though you could just consider the sequence $\{s_n\}$

Comment: @lulu Thank you. Then why is a language over alphabet a set of strings over the alphabet, and not a sequence of strings over the alphabet? Also, would a language also be finite?

Comment: There are contexts in which we want to take strings over an alphabet in a particular sequence.  For example, to formalize the notion of proofs, we would require a finite sequence of strings so that it can said each step of the proof is either justified as an axiom or by logical inference from *previous* steps.  The language is just the set of (well-formed) formulas (strings), so no sequence on those formulas is needed.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. The text you are quoting is defining the term "string over [an] alphabet" using the notions of sequence and set that you are presumed to understand. So a sequence like "notion" of letters of the alphabet is a string over the set of letters $\{i, n, o, t\}$.

Comment: A language is defined by which strings it contains.  Defining it as a sequence would just add unnecessary noise to the definition: each element would have a position in the sequence which is never used, and we would need to specify what it means if the same string appears multiple times.  I think you are getting confused with the order of the letters within a string being important.  But not the order of the strings within a language.

Answer (score 4):

A string is a sequence of symbols. Depending on the context, this might mean exclusively finite sequences or infinite sequences might be permitted.

An $X$ over a set is an $X$ whose "elements" are taken from that set ... what exactly the elements are depends on the context.

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the numbers $1, 2, 3 \cdots$.

If $\Sigma$ is an alphabet and $\Sigma^*$ is the set of strings over $\Sigma$, then each element of $\Sigma^*$ is a total function from $\{x : x \in \mathbb{N} \;\text{and}\; 1 \le x \le n \}$ to $\Sigma$, where $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ and the string in question has length $n$.

Your next question raises a subtle point.

A language $L$ is typically defined as a subset of $\Sigma^*$. The reason why $L$ is a subset in general is that it lets you rule out ill-formed strings. For example $((((x+$ is ill-formed in the language of arithmetic, but $(x+1)$ is not.

$L$ sometimes has a fairly natural ordering called the *lexicographic ordering*. If $\Sigma$ itself is ordered, then we can order any two strings relative to each other by comparing their elements one by one and arbitrarily decreeing that the *absence of an element* is less than any given element, so $ab$ would come before $aba$ in lexicographic order. However, the lexicographic ordering does not give you a *sequence* in general, for example these strings are in lexicographic order, but are not order-isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.

$$ a, aa, aaa, a^4, a^5, \cdots, b $$

Because of issues like this, it's convenient not to *insist* up front that all the strings of a given language be possible to arrange into a sequence.